# Unable to verify a public key and signature with python rsa

Tags: python, rsa

I am having trouble verifying the signature and public key in my Django server. My react-native app creates the public key and the signature.

My code looks like this:

```
import rsa

publicKey = 'MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0ukwwhq00ZmVtY1dswdVUg0tDNAbPt/GCWRUua1zsmeKT90NP3rsAEbIHJ89mQJ5/fVrl+umS5uq3F7AdZNh2R269KLV2MSytoMWR2zLD4oVUdDSwbEu8h1cx8s8vk6QpjmvZkxXYWXM1kh+9AqEjsWL3gE5hShOaqf8zl1k9pjZVywndaFi7/SsvQGy6WlSZT7cPyF/xwxGOBe3h9nijlhCIpR9AkbTSsQrVRz+iudGLSuuzS09hgX6fdqcRqR+T2UocfGJrSAqBhHVPeCksQ/OgwGJtaZQde+Cu/9FGa9LAdRcMm/WUILLlv2Dn7DGjhe/S8xvsZh7p7ghYbgxwwIDAQAB'
payload = 'some test payload'
signature = 'DB1E4dSOoA9avqhR6I2vnQQJ4Ktptsq/Z89afh0tX9gcCfWzBnkBySaeY0MjIHTOUqKimbRfFxb4NDIBCgIu/bQufIrESIl8v/U6jHPleP5wn9fh+p02mvTKUSDU8p6zBygXiGUe2SWwHaGzYvHDIW1Rm6mL22kv1qTkMhRQsVsBAgVtn8vHx6yMvN+XmQAM0Z2BDecC2kyfjZrBkJT7stzHW/1fT4GiVmoC7haaR2JRdHlGWBZXktmUvqo8xEdgYyMq582Q6N+Jw6Ic7TQc+584yviSgB3fAg32b7z5NdRVAwS2FCbLkC7DQNn+WCBk6XHOwKuu1XR9eUWU+k0Qgg=='

pem_prefix = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'
pem_suffix = '\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
key = '{}{}{}'.format(pem_prefix, public_key, pem_suffix)
public_key = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(key)

signature_bytes = base64.b64decode(signature)

rsa.verify(payload, signature_bytes , publicKey)
```

I did the above but I got the following error:

```
   result = rsa.verify(
  File "C:\Users\efosa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 356, in verify
    message_hash = compute_hash(message, method_name)
  File "C:\Users\efosa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 432, in compute_hash
    assert hasattr(message, 'read') and hasattr(message.read, '__call__')
AssertionError
```

When I try to load the signature as private key like this:

```
priv_pem_prefix = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
priv_pem_suffix = '\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
priv_key = '{}{}{}'.format(priv_pem_prefix, signature, priv_pem_suffix)

signature = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(priv_key)
```

I get the following error:

```
value, _ = decodeFun(head, asn1Spec, tagSet, length, **options)
  File "C:\Users\efosa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyasn1\codec\ber\decoder.py", line 1446, in __call__
    raise error.SubstrateUnderrunError('%d-octet short' % (length - len(substrate)))
pyasn1.error.SubstrateUnderrunError: 46-octet short
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: From the first error, `payload` is expected to have a `.read()` method. Maybe wrap it in `StringIO`?

Comment: payload must be a bytes object

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
rsa.verify(payload.encode("utf-8"), signature_bytes , publicKey)
```